# Changing levels in a MultiIndex in Python Pandas

Tags: python, reshape

I need to reverse the order of column levels from this code:

`df2=df2.pivot(index='rec_num', columns='Unique ID', values=['Maintenance  Expense Date', 'Maintenance  Expense'])`

The row index is correct, but I need a dataframe with each Unique ID having a *Maintenance Expense Date* and a *Maintenance Expense column* next to each other in pairs.  It is the reverse right now as the below output shows:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean pandas?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76460167/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, here could be your solution:

```py
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
```

This line of code will swap the first level (0) with the second level (1) in the DataFrame's columns (axis=1). After this operation, 'Unique ID' will be the first level and 'Maintenance Expense Date' and 'Maintenance Expense' will be the second level in the DataFrame's columns.